# Symfony get with criteria from OneToMany

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

Is there a way to get the items from the many side with criteria in controller?

```
    /**
 * One Content has Many Files.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IntersaxoniaBackendBundle\Entity\Content", mappedBy="sidContents", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $contents;
```

not working to get access to did from many contents:

```
$side = $em->getRepository('XYBundle:Side')->findBy(
            array('dsid' => $dsid)
        );
```

Something like:

```
$side = $em->getRepository('XYBundle:Side')->getContents()->findBy(
            array('dsid' => $dsid)
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see exactly what are you trying to achieve. What is $dsid, in which class you have `private $contents`. But it looks you need to get site that has object of class `content` with `$dsid` id.

I think it is not possible to do it this way. You can use `findBy()` method  only to load by owning side associations. So this scan be a solution:

```
$content = $em->getRepository('XYBundle:Content')->findBy(
    array('side' => $site->getId())
);
$side = $content->getSide();
```